# Windows Server 2012 R2 and Centos 7 dual boot: Windows gone from boot menu

Tags: centos, windows, dual-boot

I had in my mind that I cannot do much wrong when installing Linux (CentOS 7) after Windows (Server 2012 R2) to get all OSs as boot options.

So, after installing Server 2012 R2 nicely, I installed Centos 7. But now I only have Centos in the boot menu, no Windows anymore at all.

The things I have tried so far have failed:

- manually editing the `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` to add the entry (all my added entries were not working)
- boot-repair package is only available for ubuntu, not for centos
- running `os-prober` does not show any windows partitions
- running `fdisk -l` shows the 2 NTFS partitions (0/1) and my added Linux partitions

All installed on same HD, I turned off UEFI before install since I heard this would have complicated things even more.

I will next try the Windows repair option from install-usb-stick but have a feeling that afterwards the Centos entries will be gone.

How to get all entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offer this "Answer" as a supportive post AND as **additional information** on a point.

The **Andreas Reiff** answer with 4-step details worked very well for my situation and I learned/found an interesting "oh, by the way".

My situation was an attempt to TRIPLE-BOOT CentOS 7, Windows Server 2012, and Windows7.
I thought I would be smart and add two separate Windows `menuentry` items, one for WinServer2012 and one for Win7.

I knew each partition number and found UUID for each Windows-related partition/installation, and gave it my best shot for both to appear in the GRUB menu. Both Windows entries did appear, but one failed with a message informing me of a missing boot manager or something like that. I did notice the entry that failed did not have the asterisk in the 'Boot' column.

`Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   419432447   209715200   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       419432448   450889727    15728640   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3   *   450889728   765462527   157286400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       765462528   976773119   105655296    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`

However, the one Windows entry that did work (with '*' in the Boot column) took me to what is surely the normal WINDOWS boot manager that presented both of my Windows installations there...and each installation of Windows did successfully boot.

Aside from a different value for the UUID line, my only difference was the  `set root='(hd0, 3)'`  line that included the associated partition number.

What I ended up doing was to have

1. one GRUB `menuentry` for my CentOS 7
2. another single GRUB `menuentry` for 'anything Windows' which covered my multiple (both) Windows installations...by way of the single, boot-able NTFS entry at `/dev/sda3`.

Both Windows installations got covered by a single GRUB `menuentry`.

HOWEVER, *each of the two Windows installations appeared as **separate** entries* in the Windows boot manager...after I picked the 'anything Windows' entry from the initial GRUB menu.

I agree that running  `grub2-mkconfig`  was probably not needed. It seems to have worked without it, in my experiment.

This got the job done for me. The answer from Andreas helped me achieve what I wanted and I learned something I thought I should share, as well. And a THANK-YOU to Andreas.

Answer (score 2):

Actually.. I could manually add the entry when I get the entry correct.

For all others having same problem (system always only booting into centos):

1. to find out, on what partition Windows is actually installed (for me it is 0/sda1), run

`fdisk -l`

for me, it shows

`....
/dev/sda1 * 2048 718847 358400 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
....`

2. to find out partion UUID, run ([described here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=153988)) and find matching UUID

`blkid`

3. then add the menu entry to `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` like

`menuentry "Windows 2012 R2" --class windows --class os {
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0, 1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root XXXXXXXXXXXXX(UUID from step 2)
    chainloader +1
}`

4. I also ran `grub2-mkconfig` though I am not sure if that is really needed.

Now I also have 2012 in the boot menu.

Comment: This worked for me without running `grub2-mkconfig`.

Comment: The purpose of grub2-mkconfig is to overwrite the grub.cfg file. Of course, you need to add to the command a -o argument with the file you want the output placed. So, if you didn't use that argument, it just went to stdout and it did nothing. If you specified the file, then your edits would be lost. It is better to put your custom entry into /etc/grub.d/40_custom. Then grub2-mkconfig will incorporate that into the final product and you work will survive upgrades.